# How to get current windows user name while xampp is started by other user

Tags: php, apache

I have created php program in which i am trying to get current windows user name. I installed this on server and I have multiple users on server, for example: [(administrator -- user-1), (sam -- user-2), (mac -- user-3)] and so on.

I start my xampp using user-1 .
I start my application in localhost (localhost/myapplication/index.php)
I get correct o/p for --->administrator

```
echo getenv("username"); or echo get_current_user(); or echo trim(shell_exec('whoami'));
```

For user-2(he login to his windows session)
There is no need to start xampp as its alredy started by user-1
user-2 starts application in localhost (localhost/myapplication/index.php)(using different session with login)

When i execute

```
echo getenv("username"); or echo get_current_user(); or echo trim(shell_exec('whoami'));
```

I get o/p --> administrator instead of sam

Can you please help me in that?

Comment: Because user one started the server the session in bind to him. Thats why it still show the admin user and not user 2.

Comment: I am getting o/ p "sam" (right o/p))  when i am executing C:\Users>whoami in side cmd with windows user sam session login.

Comment: Hello Andre thanks for reply. Yes but can you please tell me how I can get current windows user name?

Comment: Yes the reason why you get the right user when you use shell is because it is bind to the logged in used. The server is bind to the admin user. I don't see how that is possible

Answer (score 0):

Its is not possible todo your way because of the the reasons I posted above. However it is possible doing other ways.

I created a C script

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *p=getenv("USER");
    if(p==NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    printf("%s\n",p);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this code. If you don't know how to do it, do a google search `How to compile C code`

Once you have compile, save the compile code in the same directory as the php script. I saved mine as `a.out`

Then in your php code do the following:

```
exec("./a.out");
```

This return the current logged in user.